# Which of the following sets in $\mathbb{R^2}$ have positive Lebesgue measure?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

For two sets $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R^2}$ we define $A+B = \{a+b \mid a \in A, b \in B \}$. Which of the following sets in $\mathbb{R^2}$ have positive Lebesgue measure?

A.  $S=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2=1\}$

B.  $S=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2<1\}$

C.  $S=\{(x,y)|x=y\}+\{(x,y)|x=-y\}$

D.  $S=\{(x,y)|x=y\}+\{(x,y)|x=y\}$

Comment: Could you show what you've tried?

Comment: @E.Lim. i tried but nothing i get..can u help me solve this problem